# Adding periodic tasks in celery (django) inside an app

Tags: python, django, celery

In celery 4> the `periodic_task` decorator is deprecated. The recommendation now is to define every periodic task inside where you initialize celery (based on what I can find, and the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries)).

In my django setup, I have a lot of small apps, and having a central place to setup period tasks won't do it.

I am still learning my way around celery, but I think my solution is "good".
Is this the wrong way to solve this, or is there another way now that `periodic_task` is gone?

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from lib.celery_instance import app  # The celery instance

@app.task()
def mytask():
    # do something...
    return 123

app.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=8, minute=45), mytask.s())
```

Comment: That looks OK, but I find that storing it in central place is much easier to maintain.

Comment: yea, I can see that it makes sense in most cases to have them centrally managed. But in this apps case, it just doesn't make sense.. Thanks!

Comment: @xeor I have been trying to update celery 3.1 to 4 in my django project, for some reason its crashing at 'auto_app_dicovery', is there something that we can do to get over it .. I know this is not related by just wondering if you could help

Comment: @kt14 `app.autodiscover_tasks()` works for me. Maybe you have an error in one of your tasks.py?

Comment: @xeor thank you, the problem is the  django server wont start and gets struck at `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`. May be I am doing something wrong, i'll check the settings again

Comment: @kt14 you shoulnt need the lambda thingy anymore. Also, try without almost any apps, then add them gradually to see which app breaks. You should create a new question tho. Comments here are not optimal.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to centrally manage the periodic tasks could be to define a dict in the settings.

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'some name': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.do_something',
        'schedule':  crontab(hour=0, minute=0),
    }
}
```